# How to use classes as properties only?

Tags: vb.net, class

I have been trying to do this for a long time but I can't find anything anywhere. I think I am not searching it as it should...

A little example:

```
Class MainClass

    Property ExampleProperty As New ExamplePropertyClass

    Private Class ExamplePropertyClass

        Sub DoSomething()

        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

In the previous code the `ExamplePropertyClass` is used as an property of the `MainClass`.
There is always an error that says **I can't expose a private class as propery**.

But how is it possible to make only the property "Visible", I mean The user who is going to use the code should only use the `property` and not the `class`, how can the `class` be not `inherited` or visible?

Comment: `I can't expose a private class as property` -- By declaring it `private`, you've told the compiler that you only want it to be used *inside the main class.*

Comment: You do this using interfaces. Make your class implement an interface and return the interface from the property.

Answer (score 0):

What is property actually syntactic sugar for setter and getter.So mostly it is default public
You declare class as private. So it will be invisible outside. Then there is conflict if it be  not visible then how people will know to assign and get that object without knowing its type. So that type should be public and visible

```
dim m as new MainClass()
m.ExampleProperty=? ' What is ExampleProperty ?int , object. So it should not be unknown
```

Another way you claim that you are not going to use that property outside.This way it is ok to have private class inside.

```
'Explicitly make property to be used only within class
Private Property ExampleProperty As ExamplePropertyClass
```

Comment: Ahh, i was sure about this, seems like i have to modify the source code.
Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You do this with interfaces:

```
Public Interface IDoesSomething
    Sub DoSomething()
End Interface


Public Class MainClass

    Public Sub New()
        m_example = New InternalClass
    End Sub

    Private m_example As IDoesSomething
    Public ReadOnly Property Example() As IDoesSomething
        Get
            Return m_example
        End Get
    End Property


    Private Class InternalClass
        Implements IDoesSomething


        Public Sub DoSomething() Implements IDoesSomething.DoSomething

        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```